# Checkbox in listview - Checkbox click marks the listview line

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I have a listview with one column like this:

```
<ListView.View>
   <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn x:Name="OnOffSwitch" Header="Enabled" Width="118">
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox Click="chkb_Click">
                      <CheckBox.Style>
                          <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                              <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                                    </Trigger>
                              </Style.Triggers>
                           </Style>
                      </CheckBox.Style>
                  </CheckBox>
               </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
   </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

and the click event like this:

```
private void chkb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        startSomething = myList.SelectedItem;
    }
```

My problem is when I don't have a line "marked" in the listview and press the checkbox nothing happends because I don't have a selectedItem. Or if I have several lines, marks line nr 1 and try to press the checkbox on line nr 2. It starts the wrong line then the one i pressed.

The easiest fix I can think of is make sure that when I press the checkbox I want it to mark the line that the checkbox I pressed are on. But I am having problems doing so.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: so if i understand this correctly, you want to mark the line in the listbox where the checkbox item has been selected?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I think that is the easiest way to make sure the click event works perfectly.

Comment: Why not use Binding?

Comment: The code shown is very simplified. I am using binding on many things, but in this case its easier this way because of some config files etc etc. so if someone cud help me find a solution on how to mark the listview line I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Used some sort of binding afterall :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tag value to your checkbox which is bound to the list view item

```
<CheckBox Click="chkb_Click" Tag="{Binding}">
```

and you can access the item which the check box belongs to in your click handler (without selecting the item before):

```
private void chkb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var startSomething = (sender as FrameworkElement).Tag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fratyx, I will try it out straight away!